# libdvbv5 - how to add support for KU-CIRCULAR standard?

Tags: dvb, linux-tv

**libdvbv5** has no option for KU-CIRCULAR LNB frequency (10750,10750,0), how to solve this?

in the Ubuntu `Yakkety Yak` libdvbv5 are used as a back end for kaffeine 2.0, and in the `kaffeine 2.0` program, doesn't exist any option for LNB with the parameters: `high 10750, low 10750, swith 0` i.e. for so-called `ku-circular` standard of Russia satellite tv. I don't know, how to create a patch for libdvbv5, to solve this problem.

I only found [this patch](https://www.mail-archive.com/kde-bugs-dist@kde.org/msg119521.html)  but that isn't what i need.

Comment: I don't know any of those words; is this a programming problem?

Comment: i've edited this question.